# Gitolite intermittent issue: 'bad interpreter: Permission denied'

Tags: teamcity, gitolite

I have an issue when TeamCity connects to the git server. We use gitolite

Error message

```
Failed for the root 'myroot' #84: List remote refs failed: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.NoRemoteRepositoryException: git@mygitserver:repo.git: bash: /home/git/.gitolite/src/gl-auth-command: /usr/bin/perl: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

This issue occurs intermittently.

Do you have any ideas how can I identify and fix the root cause?

Answer (score 0):

Check if any of the perl script have a `^M` (in which case a dos2unix would fix it).

But for the permission denied part, as in [this thread](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=157915), check if the partition is being mounted noexec (`mount`).
Especially the `/tmp` one, which can be used (or not used) depending on gitolite operation.

```
sudo mount -o remount,exec /tmp
```

Comment: @mnaoumov no, it would be intermittent, because not all gitolite operation would use `/tmp`.